# ROS Answers SE migration: Xn source code

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS files, such as XnCppWrapper.h, many functions return functions beginning with xn. For instance:

```
inline XnStatus AddNeededNode(ProductionNode& needed)
{
        return xnAddNeededNode(m_hNode, needed.m_hNode);
}
```

or

```
inline XnStatus RemoveNeededNode(ProductionNode& needed)
{
        return xnRemoveNeededNode(m_hNode, needed.m_hNode);
}
```

The ROS documentation sites, such as http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nao_openni/html/XnCppWrapper_8h_source.html do not provide code for the functions beginning with xn. The OpenNI section on git also has functions that call these xn functions. I am unable to find the definition of any of these functions on the OpenNI section however. Does anyone know where I can find the function definitions? Or are parts of OpenNI closed source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10713/xn-source-code/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `xn` code is not part of ROS. `Xn` sounds like it's part of OpenNI, so surely the code you are looking for is there.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-25**:
Not all documentation includes source code. If theirs doesn't, either download the source code from their website, or find their svn/git/mg browser and view on-line.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-07-25**:
Do you know where I can find this code? Otherwise, is there an answer site like this for OpenNI where I can ask about it? The documentation page on http://www.openni.org/documentation does not contain the source code for many of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe, you can find the function in the [OpenNi source](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1